# Implementing SVG scale/rotate transformations (and how to understand the coordinate system)

Tags: svg

So I'm a bit baffled with the SVG coordinate system. I'm doing a project that converts SVG objects into polygons (which are then shown in OpenGL). I have all the code that takes rects, circles, paths (with curve approximation), etc and turns them into a set of points for each of the objects. This is all working great so far.

I'm now at the stage where I'm implementing transformations. I have all my matrix functions written and ready to go, but I'm confused by the relationship between translate(x,y) and any 0,0-centric operation (rotation and scaling mainly).

So let's say we have an object at 0,0. `rotate(45, 100, 100)` is equivalent to `translate(100, 100) rotate(45) translate(-100, -100)`, but if I move my object to 100,100 and the rotation is still applied at 0,0 doesn't that mean the center of the rotation actually takes place at -100,-100 relative to the original position of the object?

I guess my question is how does `translate` affect the object's coordinate system? It seems that in some cases it's used to move 0,0 to the specified point *without moving the object*, and in other cases it's used to move the object.

Is my understanding of the coordinate system completely flawed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that the [SVG specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/) explains [coordinate transformations](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#TransformMatrixDefined) pretty clearly. Every transformation means multiplying the current coordinates with a 3x3 matrix. The most generic transformation that you can specify in the [`transform` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#TransformAttribute) is a custom `matrix(...)`, while all the other kinds of transformations (translate, rotate, scale, skew) are just easy to use shortcuts. In the end, everything ends up as a matrix.

Combining several transformations is simple, it just means that each transformation matrix is multiplied with the others, in order, and keeping track of all the transformations means just remembering the final 3x3 matrix obtained from this multiplication, and computing the final coordinates of an element means just multiplying the 3x1 matrix of the initial coordinates with that 3x3 matrix.

So, my advice is to just work with matrices and forget about manually applying each transformation.

Comment: I have functions for each of the transformations that turn them into matrices. This is all working perfectly. My problem is higher level, though. Doing `translate(100,100) rotate(45) translate(-100,-100)` does not center the rotation at (100,100), it centers it at (-100,-100) because it moves the object at (0,0) to (100,100). When the rotation occurs, it still occurs at (0,0). So either the spec has a typo (not likely) or I'm missing something about the coordinate system (more likely).

Comment: Don't forget that it is not the object that is changing, but the coordinate system. `translate(100, 100) rotate (45) translate(-100, -100)` doesn't mean that first you move the object by `(100, 100)`, and then rotate it, it means that you shift the origin of the coordinate system by `(100, 100)`, which has the opposite effect: the object which was supposed to be at `(100, 100)` suddenly finds itself right on the origin of the **local** coordinate system.

Comment: That makes a bit more sense. I guess my question is how do I implement this then? Because if I was to directly generate matrices for `translate(100, 100) rotate (45) translate(-100, -100)` and multiply them together, it *would* rotate around `(-100, -100)`. It seems like for translation, I would have to generate the inverse translation, and then before the actual translation is applied to the points, invert it again. Is this true?

Comment: Are you sure about that? I've [created a SVG file](http://sergiu.myxwiki.org/xwiki/bin/download/Sandbox/WebHome/a.svg) trying to exemplify what happens. The blue line is a line from (100, 100) to (100, 110) without transformations, the green line is transformed with `translate, rotate, translate back`, and the red line is transformed with `rotate around (100, 100)`. The matrix math is done according to the specification, and in the end I got the right coordinates. I placed a yellow dot on the computed coordinates, and it falls on the real line end, as obtained after transformations.

Comment: Another thing to note is that the rotation is also applied the other way around: `rotate(45)` rotates the line counter-clockwise, although the angle is positive and angles values are supposed to be clockwise.

Comment: Thanks, Sergiu. I think I figured it out with your help.